# Lua doesn't go over 'nil' in table

Tags: arrays, lua

I have such an anonymous Lua function:

```
an_func = function(x) return x == nil end
```

I need to test it on a table from 4 values: `{'None', nil, 1, '1'}`.
So, I wrote the following code:

```
for num, element in pairs({'None', nil, 1, '1'}) do
    print(num .. ': ' .. tostring(an_func(element)))
end
```

When I ran it, I got only three lines:

```
1: false
3: false
4: false
```

The line with the `true` value (corresponding to `nil` table element) didn't print.

Can you explain, why did Lua print all results, but `true`? How can I fix the snipped make it output all 4 lines?

P.S. I'm newbee in Lua.

Comment: You've tagged this [arrays] and several answers and comments use the term "array". That is confusing in that it 1) could refer to a Lua implementation's internal data structures or 2) suggest characteristics that don't carry over from other programming environments. That's why the documentation defines the concept of a [table with a sequence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1). Your table constructor does not produce a table with a sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using pairs(), it goes over all elements of a table. *nil* means *nothing*, so it won't go over it. Why should it tell you there's nothing in the table? If you have a totally new table, it'll return *nil* if you index it with anything.  `print(({}).test) --> nil`

If you really want to get the nil, you could use a dummy value:

```
local NIL = setmetatable({},{__tostring=function() return "nil" end})

an_func = function(x) return x == NIL end

for num, element in pairs({'None', NIL, 1, '1'}) do
    print(num .. ': ' .. tostring(an_func(element)))
end
```

Output:

```
1: false
2: true
3: false
4: false
```

Comment: As I understood, you have been added a metatable (analogue to properties in Python or Java) to **all tables** with `NIL`. It works for me even if I don't assign an anonymous function to `__tostring` in metatable. What is the reason to create `__tostring` ?

Comment: @VeLKert Actually he made a table called NIL that when tostring'd returns 'nil'

Comment: In his particular example he didn't need a metatable at all, he simply did so, so that if you printed it, you'd get the expected value 'nil'

Comment: As @warspyking mentioned, the metatable is more a cosmetic thing. Doing ```print(NIL)``` would now output _nil_ instead of _table: 21BA9BE8 (or similar)_. If you never intend to print it, it doesn't really matter. Also, with "all tables with NIL", I hope you just mean NIL? I've just set the metatable of NIL. When you put NIL in another table, you're just putting a reference to it. Only NIL will have that metatable. _(unless you use setmetatable etc)_

Comment: #EinsteinK I get the vibe he hasn't learned, nor understands metatables yet,  afterall he does call himself a 'newbee'

Comment: Yes, I realize I should've explained the metatable, but I forgot.

Answer (score 4):

In Lua, *everything* *(a function, string, thread, ...)* is a value, with `nil` (and technically *none/void*) being the only exception(s). To put simply, `nil` *represents the **absence** of value*. So when iterating over a table, why would Lua say there is nothing there. If it did it would have to iterate over every virtually possible index you can create.

However it appears you are using an array. You *technically* can iterate over it assuming you *know the length*. I'll make the assumption that the last item in the table is **NOT** `nil`, and that there wasn't any holes assigned after the initial length of the table with holes, however this may not necessarily be true in your case, if it isn't you will have to keep track of the length yourself and use it rather than the # operator:

```
for i = 1,#t do
    local v = t[i]
    print (v == nil)
end
```

Comment: You are really assuming that there are no holes in the array part due to how the length operator is defined. `the length of a table t is only defined if the table is a sequence` `{10, 20, nil, 40} is not a sequence, because it has the key 4 but does not have the key 3.`
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7

Comment: @Rocket2 Yet the # operator would give me 4 in your example. I understand what you're saying, but how the # operator works, I CAN use it in this way.

Comment: You can do anything you want. But nothing guarantees what you do will behave as expected in all scenarios. (undefined behavior) Here is an example that shows that the length operator has different behaviors when the same table is defined in different ways: https://repl.it/Bo97

Comment: @Rochet2 However constant testing (I've messed with this before) has taught me how to use # in a way that works for me, so running this code works quite fine, and always will. Well unless there's some metatable thing involved but there wasn't in the question.

Comment: The # operator is very tricky when it's about holes in an array. Normally, when you construct a table with _x_ elements and don't edit the table, _#table_ should return _x_. The Lua manual states that this depends on the implementation, though. If you want to be 100% sure, you would have to go over all keys and determine the highest.

Comment: @EinsteinK I treat the # operator not as the 'size-of', but the 'length-of', so basically in the way I treat it holes have no effect, as it will still return the expected length. I have never found reason to believe otherwise, but I would love some solid evidence (a code example) where it does not work to my 'rule', as then I can fix my rule and use a new one instead :D

Comment: @warspyking I already provided manual quotes and examples that break the length operator. What kind of example are you looking for exactly? It sounds like you want some evidence to prove that the operator does not work on an unedited table that has all values defined on initialization. Those are some hard restrictions and assumptions..

Comment: @Rochet2 I want an example of an array with holes, where the # operator does not return the last index in the array part containing a value.

Comment: @warspyking There is one in the link I posted in an earlier comment showing that situation. Also same thing happens if the last value is nil as you commented. Here is another example `t = {1,2,nil,4}; t[6] = 2; print(#t)` The output is 4 instead of 6.

Comment: @Rochet2 Ah, I get that now. I think I understand how it works now, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your answer has a simple misstatement. `nil` is a value. (It has type `nil`.)

Comment: @Tom You will notice I said it *represents* the absence of value. I didn't say it *has* no value.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers address your second question well but the simple explanatory  facts are [Any key with value `nil` is not considered part of the table. Conversely, any key that is not part of a table has an associated value `nil`.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) Assigning a value of `nil` removes any existing key-value pair with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop through all keys you want to print the values for.
Possible ways:

1. Know the length beforehand. (warspyking noted about this)
2. Using an end marker.
3. Calculate the length somehow (for example with maxn).
4. Use something to represent nil values. (EinsteinK showed an example
   of this)

Each has their good and bad sides, here are some:

For the first you would need to know the length beforehand in all cases which may be difficult.
The end marker is convenient, but requires you to shift around the end marker.
Calculating length would not work if the last element is nil.

Example of calculating the length - assuming last element is not nil.
Note that lua 5.1 has table.maxn that you can use instead of this custom implementation of maxn.

```
an_func = function(x) return x == nil end

function maxn(t)
    local n = 0
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if k%1 == 0 then
            n = k
        end
    end
    return n
end

local t = {'None', nil, 1, '1'}
for num = 1, maxn(t) do
    print(num .. ': ' .. tostring(an_func(t[num])))
end
```

Example of using an end marker:

```
an_func = function(x) return x == nil end

local END = {}
local t = {'None', nil, 1, '1', END}

local num = 1
while t[num] ~= END do
    print(num .. ': ' .. tostring(an_func(t[num])))
    num = num+1
end
```

Comment: maxn is deprecated, I don't think you should suggest it. And out of curiosity, since you are only dealing with arrays here why not use ipairs? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: ipairs stops at first nil, so I dont see how I would be able to use it in place of either of the loops in any way - it would stop after printing the first value.
maxn in itself is a tool for the job it is supposed to do. I guess I recommended table.maxn because it might be faster if it is implemented in C or something. Though it was removed yeah .. hmm.

All of these solutions work with any holes in the array - except the maxn assumes the last element is never nil, but otherwise any value can be nil.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, temporary brainfart. But I still wouldn't recommend ipairs even for 5.1, it introduces incompatibility, AND is deprecated anyway.